# Erro Intermitente (could not obtain ole control window handle) Delphi

Tags: delphi

Bom dia, eu tenho uma aplicação que roda em 8 mil máquinas, entretanto, estou tendo um erro numa pequena parcela(media de 100) todos os dias. 
Recebo a msg (could not obtain ole control window handle) e não consegue mais fechar essa msg em tela ate que a aplicação precisa ser fechada, o problema que ela integra com outros componentes o quais dependem de um fluxo para ser desconectado quando a aplicação for fechada.

Eu pesquisei e tentei simular tudo que foi citado, mas tudo sem sucesso, eu coloquei um Application.Message para monitorar os erros, e coloquei para não registrar o erro na tela. O problema foi mascarado mas não resolvido, no EventViewer recebo o erro dizendo que o Windows fechou a aplicação por um problema na KERNELBASE.dll.

Utilizo o delphi 7 e Windows 7 nas maquinas, minha aplicação tem um modulo de WebBrowser o qual carrega n aplicações de terceiros(Ate suspeito que alguma dessas aplicações poderiam gerar algum erro de integração).

Obrigado a todos.

Answer (score 0):

Essa mensagem de erro em específico é bem abstrata, e pode-se tratar de inúmeros erros diferentes, primeiramente verifique se as máquinas utilizadas possuem o internet explorer instalados. Caso não esteja instalado o `TWebBrowser` não vai funcionar, pois utiliza dlls do IE.